# Does flatMap with distinct give me a list out of RDD array values?

Tags: pyspark

This is my RDD, as you can see a single block can have multiple genre values:

```
  [['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy'],
     ['Adventure', 'Children', 'Fantasy'],
     ['Comedy', 'Romance'],
     ['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance'],
     ['Comedy']]
```

I wish to make a list out of the values in the arrays of the RDD, splitting all the values into multiple rows like this:

```
['Adventure',
'Drama',
'Comedy'] ....
```

and also make this collection distinct.

So far I have tried this

```
RDD.flatMap(lambda x: x).distinct().take(100)
```

But I don't know whether this code takes all the values out of all the arrays and makes a distinct list from them. The question is, does it perform the task I require it to do?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it has worked and been solved

Comment: @pault I have questions regarding becoming a data scientist is there a way I can have a conversation with you perhaps?